# Setting an array from an array pointer parameter

Tags: c++

```
Zoo::Zoo(Name* name, Location* location, Animal* animals[]) {
    this->name = name;
    this->location = location
 }
```

My `Zoo` class also has a variable named `animals` which stores an unknown amount of `Animal` objects.

How can I set this in the above constructor?

Comment: Use vectors/shared pointers

Comment: It depends: Would you be ok with sharing the `Animal` array with e.g. the caller of the constructor, or would you like your own copy? What about the actual `Animal`s within the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a C++ container, rather than a raw C array.

```
#include <vector>

Zoo::Zoo(Name* name, Location* location, const std::vector<Animal*>& animals) {
    this->name = name;
    this->location = location;
    this->animals = animals;
}
```

With `std::vector` you don't need to know how many animals there are. Your class definition would look something like this:

```
class Zoo {
    Name * name;
    Location * location;
    std::vector<Animal *> animals;
    /* ... */
};
```

If you want to go this route (I highly recommend it, and I think most of the C++ community would agree), you should look up a tutorial on the basic usage of `std::vector`, as well as some other related classes such as `std::list`, `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`, which all have their own advantages/disadvantages. I recommended `std::vector` because it's behavior is closest to that of raw C arrays, while still being safely resizable.

---

In C++, the optimal method of writing constructors that copy other objects is to make use of initialization lists. Those look like this.

```
Zoo::Zoo(Name* n, Location* l, std::vector<Animal*> a) : name(n), location(l), animals(a) {}
```

The difference here is that the `Zoo` constructor's arguments are forwarded directly to the constructors of the members of `Zoo` before the constructor's code is even run. In this case, since that is all that needed to be done, the constructor has nothing left to do and is left empty (`{}`).

Comment: so in this case, how would I declare my Zoo classes' animal member? Because I don't know its size, and I don't know what size the animals parameter will be either.

Comment: You should use the constructor initialization list.

Comment: @juanchopanza I would do that in my own code, but I wasn't sure if it would be too confusing for the OP. I'll mention it as an aside.

Comment: Wait a minute. The name **member** is of type `Name` while the name **parameter** is of type `Name*`. Doesn't this mean that in the constructor I have to say `this->name = *name`?

Comment: Not in my code. Maybe in yours. I assumed, since you had `this->name = name;` in your code that `name` was a `Name *`, not a `Name`.

Comment: If `Zoo::name` is a `Name` in your code, then you are correct, and you should assign like this: `this->name = *name;`.

Comment: Thanks, on a side note: How does `this->` imply it was a pointer?

Comment: `this->` doesn't say anything about what `Zoo::name` is. `this` is always a pointer, and therefore it must be dereferenced (`*this`) before it is used. `this->name` is a shorthand for `(*this).name`.

Comment: What tipped me off that `Zoo::name` was a pointer is that you did `this->name = name;` as opposed to `this->name = *name;`. You did not dereference `name` when assigning to `Zoo::name`.

Comment: @anthropomorphic Ah ofcourse! Sorry for these really basic questions. I'm just learning C++ from Java, which is the opposite of what you're doing according to your profile :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59040/discussion-between-anthropomorphic-and-ogen).

Comment: Who is the owner of those points (Animal) and therefore responsible to delete them

Comment: @EdHeal that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: You should pass the input vector by const reference, or use std::move on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::vector as follows

```
#include <vector>

Zoo::Zoo(Name* name, Location* location, std::vector<Animal*> animals) {
    this->name = name;
    this->location = location;
    this->animals = animals;  // where animals is an attribute in your Zoo class
 }
```

You could manually copy each of the elements from the animals array sequentially. However, this implies that either the number of elements in the array is known or the last element is set to a known value(for example NULL). The code then becomes:

```
#include <vector>

Zoo::Zoo(Name* name, Location* location, Animal** animals, size_t nAnimals) {
    this->name = name;
    this->location = location;
    // Animal **animals; // this is the attribute in Zoo
    this->animals = new Animal*[nAnimals];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nAnimals; i++) {
             this->animals[i] = new Animal(); // assuming default constructor for Animal class 
             memcpy(this->animals[i], animals[i], sizeof(Animal));
    }
```

In order to free the allocated memory use the following code in the destructor(~Animal())

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < nAnimals; i++)
                 delete this->animals[i]; 
delete[] animals;
```

Comment: Wow, looks like we wrote exactly the same code. Great minds think alike.

Comment: Same comment as for the other question: You should use the constructor initialization list.

Comment: As for the "manual copy": don't use `memcpy`to copy one `Animal` to another unless you are _really_, _really_ sure it's a POD. And even if so, I'd argument it's bad style to mix `new` and `memcpy` this way.